# I need to save tailwind.config.js file for my changes to apply

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

**UPDATE**

**I think vs code bugged out when i updated and saved the scripts in the `package.json` file, i saved the `package.json` again and restarted the site and now the problem is gone.**

i am facing this issue with tailwind css, basically when i apply a classname to an item i need to go to the `tailwind.config.js` file and save it for my changes to apply, for example, if i put a `text-6xl` i need to go to my `tailwind.config.js` file and save it for my changes to apply, now, if i change the classname on that item to `text-5xl`, the styling will reset and i need to save the `tailwind.config.js` file again for my changes to apply. This is really frustrating.

Here is my code:

`index.js`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

`app.js`

```
import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
purge: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./public/index.html"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        poppins: "'Poppins', sans-serif",
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

`navbar.jsx`

```
import React from "react";

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {/* The Item I Was Talking About... */}
      <h1 className="text-6xl text-blue-500">Navbar</h1>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

`index.css`

```
/* ./src/index.css */
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Double-check your purge config path. I had this issue because my purge path was wrong. Alternatively, you can set purge to false during dev and the problem should also go away (turn it back on in prod obviously)

Comment: Its Fixed now, i think vscode bugged out when i saved my package.json file after i updated the scripts, i saved it again, restarted the site and now its ok.